# Bieberbach theorem for compact, flat Riemannian orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, affine-geometry

In his thesis, Bieberbach solved  [Hilbert 18 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_eighteenth_problem) and
proved that any compact, flat Riemannian manifold is a 
quotient of a torus. I need a reference to an orbifold version
of this result: any compact, flat Riemannian manifold $M$ is a 
quotient of a torus.

It should not be hard to prove: we should take the development
map and it should give a local isometry from the orbifold
universal cover of $M$ to ${\Bbb R}^n$. The corresponding
monodromy action defines a homomorphism from the orbifold
fundamental group of $M$ to the group of affine isometries.
The rotational part of its image is finite by Margulis lemma.

However, I am pretty sure it's published somewhere,
and it's always safer (and more ethical) to cite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need a textbook reference you could use "Bieberbach Groups and Flat Manifolds" by L. S. Charlap or "Spaces of constant curvature by J. A Wolf.

Comment: does it have the  result stated for orbifolds?

Comment: They don't use the word "orbifold". Everything is stated for discrete isometry groups of $\mathbb R^n$. Which is the same thing because flat orbifolds are good.

Comment: It seems you are unaware of the fact  that complete nonpositively curved orbifolds are good (i.e., developable). This is due to Gromov (I think) and proved e.g. in Bridson-Haefliger "Metric spaces of nonpositive curvature".

Comment: thanks, I would look in this book

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bieberbach‘s 1911-12 paper ([part 1](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0070?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[313],%22view%22:%22thumbnails%22%7D), [part2](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0072?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[414],%22view%22:%22thumbnails%22%7D)) proves a result about groups rather than manifolds, and it does not assume the groups to be torsion-free. In today’s language it says that a discrete, cocompact group of Euclidean isometries contains its subgroup of translations (which is necessarily a free Abelian group) as a subgroup of finite index. So you can just cite Bieberbach.

Comment: I also need to prove that the development map is globally defined.
For example, for an orbifold CP^1 with one conical point, there is
no globally defined development map, because it is simply connected.

Comment: This example is not flat. It is not a good orbifold (i.e., does not have a manifold cover) and in particular has no universal covering, on which the developing map could be globally defined.

Comment: However, if an orbifold has a universal covering, then the standard construction of a developing map works.

Comment: And a geometric orbifold (e.g., a flat orbifold) always has a manifold cover and hence a universal covering. This should be in Thurston‘s lecture notes.

Answer (score 3):

Besides Charlap's book (already mentioned in comments above), I think the following reference can be very helpful in situating these concepts with more modern language, despite not specifically mentioning "orbifolds":

> P. Buser, A geometric proof of Bieberbach’s theorems on crystallographic groups, Enseign. Math. (2), 31 (1985), 137–145.